# Toolbox from 10.0 causes an ArcGis 10.1 crash

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arctoolbox

I'm trying to open a toolbox prepared in ArcGis 10.0 in ArcGis 10.1 but it crashes the entire application. No error message is shown.

Any ideas what might cause the problem? Or how to debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. I didn't have the PATH and PYTHONPATH variables set correctly. Apparently if the ArcGis 10.1 doesn't find a python interpreter it crashes silently...

I found the solution at:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/60080-ArcMAP-10.1-Crashes-opening-the-ArcToolbox-window.

Go to Advanced system settings. In the window that comes up, go to the Advanced tab, then at the bottom click Environment Variables. Click in the list of system variables and start typing Python, and repeat for System variables, just to make certain that you don't have mis-set variables for PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME. Next, add new system variables: PYTHONPATH, set to C:\Python27\ ArcGIS10.1. PYTHONHOME, set to C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\ 
set PATH=%PYTHONHOME%;%PATH%

Comment: Can you expand on your answer? I might have the same problem

Comment: @dassouki Try adding to your PATH environment variable a path to your arcgis python installation (in my case: C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1). You can find instructions for setting environment variables on the internet.

Comment: I have that in my enviro variables, but I can't access the toolbox still on my win7 64bit machine

Comment: @dassouki Try following other instructions in the link I supplied about permissions in Python27 catalog and also try running the interpreter and importing arcpy. Maybe the installation itself is broken.